# Difference between Statement-based replication and Write-ahead log (WAL) shipping?

Tags: logging, replication, distributed

I am reading book DDIA(Designing Data-Intensive Applications) and found these two ways of implementing replication logs. They both seem to be maintaining a log of all 'write in'.
Can anyone explain to me where is the core difference of them?

Answer (score 0):

The statement are the logs of statements, sql statement for SQL, thus less data written to log files. When updates or deletes affect many rows, this results in much less storage space required for log files. Its just replicate the application level operates to the database.

The wal are the logs of changes to data files. Using WAL results in a significantly reduced number of disk writes, because only the log file needs to be flushed to disk to guarantee that a transaction is committed, rather than every data file changed by the transaction. Its replicate the low-level database storage engine instructuiions